# How can I distinguish design-time from runtime in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to display a placeholder image in a view when the constructor for a custom view I've created is executed design-time instead of runtime, i.e. by Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA. Is there any code I can write to detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a condition based on the `isInEditMode()` property. It will return true when the view is inflated inside the IDE (and emulator I think) but false when run on an actual device.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode()